# database disk image is malformed ruby on rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

> database disk image is malformed
>
> Extracted source (around line #91):
>
> ```
> #
> def prepare sql
>   stmt = SQLite3::Statement.new( self, sql )
>   return stmt unless block_given?
>
>   begin
> ```

is what i'm getting when i run *rails server*
bundle exec rake test says 0 errors

found the solution:

> rake db:drop rake db:create rake db:migrate

Comment: Sounds like something happened to your development db file image.

Comment: hello dave. thank you for your reply. how do i go about fixing this?

Comment: for anyone stuck with a database error <br/>

>rake db:drop
>rake db:create
>rake db:migrate

Comment: @AndrewK You wouldn't want to do that with a populated database of course. Were you able to do `rails db` successfully? Alternatively, could you access it directly using the sqlite runtime? (ie `sqlite db/development.db`)

Comment: @PaulRichter thankfully i was just starting and so I was able to run with remaking it. It worked but I see what you mean - this would not work with a populated database.

Comment: Please answer in an answer rather than making the question solved and answering it in the question.